# $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ linear with $n > 1$. Then there is $M$ with $\dim M = 2$ and $T(M) \subset M$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear map, with $n > 1$. Prove that there is a subspace $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, with  $\dim M = 2$ such that $T(M) \subset M$.

This question is from my list of eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I don't want a solution to the question, my problem is that I really don't know how to approach the question. I think some hints should enough.

---

**Using hints:** Is $\lambda = a + bi \in \mathbb{C}^n$ is a non-real eigenvalue, so
$$Ah = \lambda h \Longrightarrow A(h_1 + ih_2) = (a + bi)(h_1 + ih_2) \Longrightarrow Ah_1 + iAh_2 = ah_1 - bh_2 + i(ah_2 + bh_1),$$
from where
$$Ah_1 = ah_1 - bh_2;\quad Ah_2 = bh_1 + ah_2.$$
Thus, $Ah_1, Ah_2 \in Span(h_1,h_2)$. Therefore, $Span(h_1,h_2)$ is two-dimensional invariant provided that $h_1, h_2$ are LI. How to ensure that?

Now, suppose that $T$ has no complex eigenvalues. If at least two real eigenvalues are distinct, is straighforward. But what about if no?

Comment: What if $T$ is in Jordan normal form?

Comment: @copper.hat I didn't know it would be necessary, but the Jordan Normal Form is the next part, so I would like to solve without using it.

Comment: So, it is just saying to prove there exists an invariant subspace of T whose dimension is 2. Are you sure no other information is given?

Comment: @KNilesh yes. I wrote the question exactly as it is in the list.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is the real matrix associated to $T$. If $A$ has a non-real eigenvalue $\lambda$, and $Av=\lambda v$ for some $v\in\mathbb C^n$, then try to find an invariant subspace with aids of $v$.

Comment: Or if $T$ has two real eigenvalues then the answer is straightforward.

Comment: I updated my question trying to use your hints.

Comment: If you have a repeated eigenvalue things are even easier: any 2 dimensional subspace of your eigenspace will satisfy $T(M) \subset M$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom because in this case, $A = \lambda I_n$, right?

Comment: But the eigenspace might only have dimension 1.

Comment: @S.Dolan I had thought of $Ah = \lambda h$ for all $h$, so must be $A = \lambda I_n$. Thus if $h_1, h_2$ are LI, $Ah_1 = \lambda h_1, Ah_2 = \lambda h_2$ are LT too.

Comment: Yes, that would be true but I think the real issue is dealing with the case when there is only one eigenvector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there with your solution using the hints.

> Complex eigenvalue case

Note that if $T(v)=\lambda v$, by taking complex conjugates, $T(v^*)=\lambda^* v^*$. Then $\lambda $ and $\lambda^* $ are unequal and therefore $v$ and $v^* $ are independent.

> All eigenvalues real case

We have $T(v)=\lambda v$. Similarly, $T$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^n/(v)$ will have a real eigenvalue (which may of course also be $\lambda$). If the corresponding eigenvector is $(v)w$ then the requisite 2-dimensional subspace is generated by $v$ and $w$.

Comment: I got it! Thank you!